# Server Sent Event with NestJS

Tags: nestjs, microservices, server-sent-events

I would like send an event when a module is created, updated or deleted. I read the documentation **NestJS** **SSE** but it didn't help.

Here is how my methods look like and already created a controller.

```
addNewModule(data: ApiGateway.Event.AddModule.IPayload) {
    this.logger.debug('Handle event on add new module!');
    this.logger.debug(`Previous modules state: ${this.modules}`);
    this.modules.push(data.moduleInfo);
    this.logger.debug(`New modules state: ${this.modules}`);
  }

  removeModule(data: ApiGateway.Event.RemoveModule.IPayload) {
    this.logger.debug('Handle event on add new module!');
    this.logger.debug(`Previous modules state: ${this.modules}`);
    this.modules = this.modules.filter(module => {
      return module.name !== data.moduleName;
    });
    this.logger.debug(`New modules state: ${this.modules}`);
  }

  updateModuleSettings(data: ApiGateway.Event.UpdateModuleSettings.IPayload) {
    this.logger.debug('Handle event on add new module!');
    this.logger.debug(`Previous modules state: ${this.modules}`);
    this.modules.find((module, index) => {
      if (module.name === data.moduleInfo.name) {
        this.modules[index] = data.moduleInfo;
        return true;
      }
    });
    this.logger.debug(`New modules state: ${this.modules}`);
  }
```

I would like to know the best way to implement SSE whenever one these methods is called. First time trying to use SSE with Nestjs.

Thanks in advance)